# Testing Akka Actors Fault Tolerance

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am learning how to use Akka actors and I found this example on Fault Tolerance from Akka documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fault-tolerance.html).

```
class Parent extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    override val supervisorStrategy =
            OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
            case _: ArithmeticException ⇒ Resume
            case _: NullPointerException ⇒ Restart
            case _: IllegalArgumentException ⇒ Stop
            case _: Exception ⇒ Escalate
    }
    def receive = {
        case p: Props ⇒ sender ! context.actorOf(p)
    }
}

class Child extends Actor {
    var state = 0
    def receive = {
        case ex: Exception ⇒ throw ex
        case x: Int ⇒ state = x
        case "get" ⇒ sender ! state
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a test class to control the Parent and Child classes. This class should have a method to do the initialization part and another method to send messages to the child instance.

I need help in organizing the class. In Java I would declare the ActorSystem, Parent, and Child as instance variables and use them inside the methods. But I am not sure how to do this in Scala.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way. But I think that it should work.

```
object Application {
   def main(args : Array[String]) {
     val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
     val parent = system.actorOf(Props[Parent], "parent")
     (parent ? Props[Child]).mapTo[ActorRef].foreach { child =>
        child ! new IllegalArgumentException("Oh my")
     }
   }       
}
```

Also I recommend you to [lookup the akka scala documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html).